# move middle div down if window gets smaller

Tags: html, css

I have three divs side by side. If the browser window gets smaller I want that the middle div moves down under the first div and the right div moves to the "middle".

For a better understanding, i made following outline
[image]

Can someone please tell me how you'd do this?

Comment: maybe changing the flow from top to bottom (instead of left-right) when the window is narrow might do the [trick](http://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/).

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want a responsive page but you want to change the order in which the divs display when the layout changes? ie. if it was a 'standard' responsive page the green div would be underneath the blue div, so you want to change the order?

Comment: Change source code order to 1 - 3 - 2, and float 1st to the left, 3rd to the right …

Comment: @Candlejack i don´t want to change the order. Normaly if the layout is getting smaller the green box would move down. But I want the red block moving down under the blue block, so the green box is on the right side of the blue one

Comment: @Ich, ah I see. I believe I have misinterpreted your goals, in which case I will vote to remove my answer as it does not follow the spirit of your enquiry.

Comment: *" I want that the middle div moves down under the first div and the right div moves to the "middle"."* - Is it just me who can't see this happening in the accepted answer..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpcoddkm/12/) should get you started. I forked Candlejack's fiddle, and tried to provide a css only solution.

Basically you put the 2nd div last:

```
<section id='container'>
  <div id='box-1' class='myBox'>1</div>
  <div id='box-3' class='myBox'>3</div>
  <div id='box-2' class='myBox'>2</div>
</section>
```

Then you float left div-1 and div-2 while the div-3 floats right, div-1 and div-3 have display: block; while div-2 display: inline-block;

```
#container { display:inline-block; width:100%; padding: 0.5em 0; border: 1px solid black;}
.myBox { display:inline-block; min-height: 100px; width:300px; margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3%; float:left; display: block; }
#box-1 { border:1px solid blue;}
#box-2 { border:1px solid red; display: inline-block; float: left;}
#box-3 { border:1px solid green;float:right;}
```

Comment: "*I want that the middle div moves down under the first div and the right div moves to the "middle"."* - i don't see this happening..!

Comment: i think if the op chose this answer as the right one it works for him, and yes it is happening.

Comment: as far as i checked, the last div stays where it is... strange

Comment: now I understand what you mean, anyway I think it worked for OP, for moving the third div to the right you just could add something like this "@media only screen and (max-width: XXXpx) { #box-3: { float: left; } }". Maybe OP figured it out by himself using my answer as a starting point, maybe the fiddle really is the thing that OP needed ... sorry for my english in this comment

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick trick, however you may need to tweek a bit.
http://jsfiddle.net/bd9yczqq/3/

```
[        <div><div class="box first"></div>
<div class="box middle"></div>
<div class="box last"></div></div>

.box{
width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #999;
    margin:5px 1%;
    background-color:#ccc;

}
.middle{

   float:right;
}

.last{
background-color:red;
}]
```

Comment: When I view your fiddle, the red box (ie the last one in the markup) is already seen in the middle. My understanding of the question is that the order of the boxes should only change when the window is resized. Could you clarify for me if your fiddle is intentionally showing the final order only?

Answer (score -2):

Use relative positioning in your css for your divs and float them. Example:

```
position:relative;
float:left;
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I told you to use absolute position. It's relative!